# Can <caption> elements contain links and headings?

Tags: html

Can I stuff `<a>` and `<h2>` elements inside a `<caption>` element located within a table? In browsers it looks fine, but is it ok to do it?

Comment: You can always input you html source here http://validator.w3.org/ and get to check on validation of your html source

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Any flow content - i.e. the same elements you can have directly under `<body>` - except for `<table>` are fine in a `<caption>` element.

Answer (score 1):

By the specification, the [`caption` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#edef-CAPTION) may contain inline elements only. So `<a>` is OK, `<h2>` is not. There should be no reason to use `h2` markup there, since the `caption` element itself is heading-like; with CSS, you can style it visually more heading-like if you wish.

Comment: h2 in caption is OK in HTML5, but not in HTML 4.01. Question is not wholly clear as to which applies, but is tagged HTML5.